# Not able to fetch Term store and related terms using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, taxonomy

I want to fetch termstore, Termsets and related terms. However, I'm not able to fetch the termstore.

I'm receiving the error message:

> 404 not found

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {    
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {    
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {
                 context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                 //Call your code here.
                 getTermStores();    
            });    
         });   
    });    
});

function getTermStores() {   
    session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    termStores = session.get_termStores();
    context.load(session);
    context.load(termStores);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
          termStoresEnum = termStores.getEnumerator();
          var termStores = "Term Stores: /n";

          while (termStoresEnum.moveNext()) {   
                var currentTermStore = termStoresEnum.get_current();
                var termStoreID = currentTermStore.get_id();  
                var termStoreName = currentTermStore.get_name();  
                termStores += "Name: " + termStoreName + " ID:" + termStoreID;  
         }   
    }, function(){    
          //failure loading termstores.    
    }); 
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two different errors :

1. context is defined outsite the function,
   put `context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` in your function
2. you redefined a variable with "termStores" name, not correct

Please find below the correction :

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";      
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {    
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {


             //Call your code here.
             getTermStores();    
        });    
     });   
}););

function getTermStores() {   
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStores = session.get_termStores();
context.load(session);
context.load(termStores);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
      termStoresEnum = termStores.getEnumerator();
      var termStoresNames = "Term Stores: /n";

      while (termStoresEnum.moveNext()) {   
            var currentTermStore = termStoresEnum.get_current();
            var termStoreID = currentTermStore.get_id();  
            var termStoreName = currentTermStore.get_name();  
            termStoresNames += "Name: " + termStoreName + " ID:" + termStoreID;  
     }   
}, function(){    
      //failure loading termstores.    
});}
```

Regards,